# Grails - Request and Response - Get which URL Requested the constructor

Tags: url, grails, request

I am new to Grails. Please read my scenario and provide me the best solution.

I have a controller to edit and this controller gets request from multiple pages. What I want is , the controller gets request from some page and processes request and I want the page gets redirected to similar page which requested the task.

I hope my question is clear enough. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

see [redirect](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/redirect.html) method of controller. there is also [forward](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/forward.html) method that can be useful

Comment: Add some page specific parameter to request coming from page. And check it in your controller something like if(params.myParamName == 'spegialPage') { ... }